# Converting VTK to DICOM

Tags: c#, file, vtk, dicom

I'm not expert at all with file conversion, so i'm asking for your help.
I'm working on a medical database, from which i pulled out a DICOM file.

The images inside the DICOM files have then been converted in a single `.VTK` file, on which i have to work on.

Now i need to convert again the `.VTK` file back into a DICOM file (and load it in the database).

Is there a way to do that?

(the first conversion is made by a c# script. the script read the database and convert the original dicom.
i cannot write on the database, so i have to convert the `.vtk` file outside the medical platform)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [vtkGDCMImageWriter](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.4/html/classvtkGDCMImageWriter.html). It is available in C#, so you should be able to write:

```
vtkGDCMImageWriter writer = vtkGDCMImageWriter.New();
writer.SetFileName( outfilename );
writer.SetInputConnection( reader.GetOutputPort() );
writer.Write();
```

See for example [here](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.4/html/HelloVTKWorld_8cs-example.html).

Comment: Hi Malat, thanks for your suggestion. I'll try as soon as possible.